# OS = Unknown find in installation log of my application. What is the mean of this?

Tags: windows, operating-system, installation, windows-installer

One of our customer installed our window desktop application(.exe) on his machine. But unable to launch it. He tried to run the application by clicking on the shortcut or using command line. But nothing happened, no error message. Application process was also not in the task manager. Even he tried after reboot the system but nothing changed.

One more thing installation log also contained the MsiSystemRebootPending=1. Is this the root cause ?

Comment: I suspect your app needs more debugging code. If it started and immediately stopped without crashing, how would you know? It's not clear that the install is at fault until you find out what's wrong. MsiSystemRebootPending is extremely unlikely to be anything to do with it, and after a reboot it would be irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I studied about os=unknown and MsiSystemRebootPending=1. But just want to know more about them to ensure that there was nothing due to these two. Issue was related to some external program(virus) that preventing the application from launching and running it in background same as virus.